# How to redirect to a specific folder when a specific endpoint gets hit

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a folder `/home/ubuntu/app/build` which can serve that build file when opened. All I want it when I hit the `/chat` endpoint it should redirect to this build folder `/home/ubuntu/app/build` and this build file should be served in the browser. How can I achieve this in nginx

Comment: Set up a Virtual Host or Server Block in conf file for your path /chat. Can you show your current server block file?

Comment: What I know is I can configure the ```/etc/nginx/sites-available/default``` file to achieve this. But not sure how to do that exactly.

Comment: Please read here - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04 and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-nginx-server-and-location-block-selection-algorithms